# Add two instances of my class

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, addition

I want to add to instances of my class `Bar` as such:

```
x = Bar([5, 12, 5])
y = Bar([4, 5, 6])
x+y #Bar([9, 17, 11])
```

Here is the class:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.items = arr
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Bar("+str(self.items)+")"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to implement an `__add__` method for your class:

```
def __add__(self, new):
    newlst = [];
    for i, j in zip(self.items, new.items):
        newlst.append(i+j)
    return Bar(newlst)
```

As such:

```
>>> x = Bar([5, 12, 5])
>>> y = Bar([4, 5, 6])
>>> x+y
Bar([9, 17, 11])
```

---

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.items = arr
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Bar("+str(self.items)+")"
    def __add__(self, new):
        newlst = [];
        for i, j in zip(self.items, new.items):
            newlst.append(i+j)
        return Bar(newlst)
```